# ajax laravel not inserting or code not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

i want to insert to the database by ajax crud i am inserting but the code dosn't work iam using jquery javascript framework

i want to insert to the database by ajax crud i am inserting but the code dosn't work iam using jquery javascript framework

i dont' know why although i am writing correctly
please help
here is my code
my blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="matgin-top:50px;">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-hehader bg-primary text-white">Add new product</div>
                    <form id="form" action="{{route('products.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        @method('POST')
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">product name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                            <span class="text-danger error-text product_name_error"></span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">product image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
                            <span class="text-danger error-text product_name_error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header bg-primary">All Products</div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url:$(form).attr('action'),
                    method:$(form).attr('method'),
                    data:new FormData(form),
                    processData:false,
                    dataType:'json',
                    contentType:false,
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $(form).find('span.error-text').text('');
                    },
                    succes:function(data){
                        if(data.code == 0){
                            $.each(data.error, function(prefix,val){
                                $(form).find('span.'+prefix+'_error').text(val[0]);
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            $(form)[0].reset();
                            alert(data.msg);
                            // fetchAllProducts();
                        }
                    }    
                })
            });
            
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my controller store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
         $path = 'files/';
         $file = $request->file('product_image');
         $file_name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

      //    $upload = $file->storeAs($path, $file_name);
      $upload = $file->storeAs($path, $file_name, 'public');

         if($upload){
             Product::insert([
                 'name'=>$request->name,
                 'image'=>$request->image,
             ]);
             return response()->json(['code'=>1,'msg'=>'New product has been saved successfully']);
         }
     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I check out your controller portion and found something messy, would you mind trying with the below code:

```
if ($request->has('image')) {
$fileName = time() . '_' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->image->storeAs('Files', $fileName, 'image');

$product = new Product();
$product->name = $request->name;
$product->image = $fileName;
$product->save();
return response()->json(['code'=>1,'msg'=>'New product has been saved 
successfully']);
}
```